# Wildcard SSL certificates, EV

Tags: magento, ssl-certificate, litespeed

I run a Magento e-commerce store with multiple subdomains for an affiliate program, plus a main store. Example, foo.example.com and bar.example.com are affiliates, www.example.com is my main store. They all share the same code and database and the same virtual host. Currently I have a wildcard certificate which works fine for everything. However, I was looking at EV certificates to increase customer confidence (which is not possible with wildcard certificates -- or so I'm told).

What would be the simplest setup to have both an EV SSL Cert for the main store and a wildcard for the affiliate subdomains? Two virtual hosts? By the way, I'm running Litespeed as a webserver.

Comment: Multiple Virtual Hosts sounds like the place to start but I don't know anything about Litespeed software. It doesn't look like very popular software (at least on [SF]), if you don't get an answer here their official Forum may be a good place to look for help as well. They also offer paid support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having different SSL certificates on the same IP address is not really feasible. There is [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), but it's not widely supported enough. Your only real option is to run the virtual hosts on different IP addresses.

Comment: Yes, I will be using different IP addresses

Comment: Then you want two virtual hosts running on separate IP addresses, with a different SSL certificate for each IP. I'm not sure how you do that in Litespeed though.